# Episerver customise complex data type in grid in edit mode

Tags: episerver, episerver-9

Im currently working on episerver 9 cms.

I have my pages/blocks as follows:

```
    public class  MenuBlock : SiteBlockData
    {

        [Display(
            Name = "Menu title",
            Description = "* Required",
            GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content,
            Order = 1)]
        public virtual string MenuTitle { get; set; }


        [Display(
          Name = "Section",
          Description = "Add menu sections",
          GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content,
          Order = 3)]
        [EditorDescriptor(EditorDescriptorType = typeof(CollectionEditorDescriptor<SectionBlock>))]
        public virtual IList<SectionBlock> Section { get; set; }

  }

public class SectionBlock
    {
        [Display(
            Name = "Section name",
            Description = "Select the Menu Image",
            GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content,
            Order = 1)]
        public virtual string SectionName { get; set; }

        [Display(
          Name = "Dishes",
          Description = "Dishes",
          GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content,
          Order = 2)]
        [EditorDescriptor(EditorDescriptorType = typeof(CollectionEditorDescriptor<DishBlock>))]
        public virtual IList<DishBlock> Dishes { get; set; }
    }

public class DishBlock
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dish name is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Dish name",
            Description = "* Required",
            GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content,
            Order = 1)]
        public virtual string DishName { get; set; }

        [Display(
            Name = "Dish description",
            Description = "",
            GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content,
            Order = 2)]
        [UIHint(UIHint.Textarea)]
        public virtual string DishDescription { get; set; }

        [Display(
            Name = "Price",
            Description = "",
            GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content,
            Order = 4)]

        public virtual double Price { get; set; }

    }
```

Now In CMS, edit mode, it is rendered as
[image]

As you can see, Dishes are rendered as [object object] instead of dishName.

Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: The PropertyList editor is still in beta, and it has no way of properly rendering complex types in that use case (as opposed to strings, integers, etc). We have solved this in our projects by using a custom editor.

Comment: @TedNyberg:
Thanks for your feedback. In that case, will  you be able to me how did u resolve it ? Any tutorial/link would be great. How can we use custom editor and solve it.

Comment: We inherited the original `CollectionEditor` editor to override how objects are rendered. Make sure you have the UI sources NuGet package to be able to look at the source code of the Episerver native editor.

Comment: @TedNyberg:
  
I tried same approch as below:
public class SectionCollectionEditorDescriptor : CollectionEditorDescriptor<SectionBlock>
    {

        public override void ModifyMetadata(ExtendedMetadata metadata, IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
        {
            //In metadata , i can see all dish properties and other properties but not sure what to do here to customise grid   
     
       base.ModifyMetadata(metadata, attributes);
        }
      
    }

Comment: Can you just assist me what to override in  ModifyMetadata() to customise grid ?

Comment: I wouldn't change anything in `ModifyMetadata`, see answer for a bit more info. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own Dojo widget inheriting `CollectionEditor` and customize how the items are rendered.

You'd then specify your custom editor using the `EditorDescriptor` attribute for the applicable `PropertyList` properties.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response :)
One last thing...I'm not much aware about Dojo widget....So if you can share any good link for creating EditorDescriptor using Dojo widget...that would be great for me. Or any tutorials, you would like to share.

Comment: You'll find some examples here: https://tedgustaf.com/blog/dojo (not exactly the same use case with PropertyList, but hopefully it'll get you started in the right direction).

Comment: Can you plz just assist me nuget command to download UI sources to be able to look at the source code of the Episerver native editor ? 
many thnks

Comment: It's called `Episerver.CMS.UI.Sources`: https://nuget.episerver.com/en/OtherPages/Package/?packageId=EPiServer.CMS.UI.SOURCES

Comment: I believe this is similar to what Ted is describing: https://gregwiechec.com/2015/12/propertylist-with-images/

Not exactly trivial stuff.